# trouble using osgi RESTEasy 3

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, resteasy

Hello i'm trying to create a plugin with eclipse to use RESTEasy 3 in a opensource project (iDempiere ERP).

I created a plugin with eclipse, imported the RESTEsy libraries..
I writing the following class using some tutorials on web and registering this class as Activator.

```
public class Activator extends Application implements BundleActivator {

  private volatile ServiceTracker   serviceTrackerForResteasyService;
  private volatile ResteasyService  resteasyService;
  private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

public Activator()
{

}

@Override
public void start( BundleContext bundleContext ) throws Exception
{

    try
    {
        serviceTrackerForResteasyService =  new ServiceTracker( bundleContext, ResteasyService.class.getName(), null );
        serviceTrackerForResteasyService.open();
        resteasyService = (ResteasyService)serviceTrackerForResteasyService.getService();

        if (resteasyService == null) {
            System.out.println("resteasyService == null");
        }

        resteasyService.addSingletonResource("/rest/*", new SampleResource2());


    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
```

but I have this error: resteasyService is null...
I don't know how initialize correctly the class.

I have already used successfully RESTEasy with tomcat without OSGI and I used web.xml configuration files.
In OSGI I think that the web.xml is not used anymore is it correct ?

Comment: Are those https://sarbarian.wordpress.com/2010/03/07/resteasy-and-osgi-perfect-match/ the instructions you are following?

Comment: I tried starting with those but I've seen that are obsolete.